# Opening safari existing tab

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am currently trying to build an approach to let user open the customURL app from safari, and once a unique transaction is completed, let user go back to the safari within the same tab.

I have tried used this particular method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

but the annotation here comes null, however I do get the url, and sourceApplication here. Is there anyway I can use the sourceApplication (com.xxxx.Safari), and re-open the safari without prompting the url?

Or, is it possible to close the current tab after opening getting the some transaction completed within the ios app? Not sure if we have such access with respect to accessing safari. I noticed there are some shortcut keys being introduced in ios7 but its more restricted to actual keyboard, unless if someone knows what does "cmd" key represents in ios so I can give a shot trying it natively.